# OnItemClickListener and OnClickListener not working for ListView using BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

Here is my code which is not working

I'm getting data from server using `AsyncTask` and set data to the `listview` using `baseadapter` but using `convertview.setonclicklistner` working in adapter class and below code contains in `Fragmentclass(import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;)` so I think it is not problematic

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_restaurants, container, false);
    restaurant_list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.restatrant_lv);

    no_restaturants=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.no_restaturants);

    // listening to single list item on click
    restaurant_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            Log.e("temp","temppppp");

        }
    });

    //set layout slide listener
    rowItems = new ArrayList<>();

    history_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    list_adapter = new ViewAdapter(getActivity(),rowItems);
    restaurant_list.setAdapter(list_adapter);
}
```

What is the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

If any ListView contains focusable or clickable view then OnItemClickListener won't work. In that case we need to use this.

---

Try to set your setOnClickListener after setting the adapter:

Like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_restaurants, container, false);
    restaurant_list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.restatrant_lv);

    no_restaturants=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.no_restaturants);


    //set layout slide listener
    rowItems = new ArrayList<>();

    history_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    list_adapter = new ViewAdapter(getActivity(),rowItems);
    restaurant_list.setAdapter(list_adapter);

// listening to single list item on click
        restaurant_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            Log.e("temp","temppppp");

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: yeh i tried that also but still not working... :( @Sac

Comment: can  you post your .xml file

Comment: Do you have any focusable item in your xml?

Comment: https://shrib.com/?v=nc#R43JRTu6HnNbsjOKhorq here is the link of xml file @Mohammad nabil

Comment: yeh i added this two line of code in listview also..    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:focusable="false"

Comment: do you have any button in custom_list_item.xml file?, if possible ps post custom_list_item.xml / screenshot

Comment: at the end it contains feedback layout with button and xml layout looks like this..http://4.1m.yt/EtgpV-R.png @Mohammad nabil

Comment: @alias26 give this a try android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
in root view of your listview item.

Comment: yeh this worked for me...android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" @Sac  but what is the reason ..? because before this project i'm not used that still listview.setOnclicklistner working..

Comment: I have updated the answer for explanation. Mark answer accepted if it helped you.

Comment: can u please send your mail_id for discussion ..more about it.. and i removed clickable items from xml still not worked in that..

Comment: lets chat on http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ if you need to discuss it more.

Answer (score 0):

add id to your parent layout for custom_list_item.xml

```
holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickItem(position));

private class OnClickItem implements View.OnClickListener{
    private int mPostion;

    public OnClickItem(int position){
        mPostion = position;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        YourActivity yourActivity = (YourActivity) mContext;
        yourActivity.onItemClicked(mPostion);
    }
}
```

Comment: it showing error in  "yourActivity.onItemClicked(mPostion);" this line.. but i already used like this in another projects and it was worked but in this project not working... dontknow why...even setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren is also not worked